# get gmail Xoauthtoken ,access gmail mails?

Tags: android, gmail, imap, token, pop3

Hi everyone,
            finally, after not getting any solution for deleting the mails using contentprovider ,i moved to IMAP/POP3 libraries.Ive used [xoauth](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode#Exploring_the_sample_code) library to connect to IMAP , but its `connectToImap` method use six parameter and i m unable to get two parameters `oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret`.Please tell me how to get these??

~~~

```
      public static IMAPSSLStore connectToImap(String host, int port,
            String userEmail, String oauthToken, String oauthTokenSecret,
            OAuthConsumer consumer, boolean debug) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH");
        props.put(XoauthSaslClientFactory.OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP, oauthToken);
        props.put(XoauthSaslClientFactory.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET_PROP,
                oauthTokenSecret);
        props.put(XoauthSaslClientFactory.CONSUMER_KEY_PROP,
                consumer.consumerKey);
        props.put(XoauthSaslClientFactory.CONSUMER_SECRET_PROP,
                consumer.consumerSecret);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
        IMAPSSLStore store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, unusedUrlName);
        final String emptyPassword = "";
        store.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);
        return store;
    }
~~~
```